logic deadlock: Original question can (and maybe should) remain closed, Q&A to modified closed as duplicate
My apologies (esp. to @SamGibson who very gracefully handles this) for making the situation complicated.
We have an original question, How to design a Hardware Solution for Duplicating Mouse Events to multiple devices , which was originally indeed not great – all design effort in there was getting a nonsensical recommendation from ChatGPT, a significant part of the question was "can't I buy something like that?". But there was a valuable question asked, and the poster did ask about how to design a device to fulfill that role.
So, after the question was closed, I went in and edited it to remove the AI-generated nonsense, and the shopping question, and to highlight the design aspect in the title. Sadly, I did so immediately after clicking on (vote to) "reopen", which promptly (and correctly) led to a "remains closed, original concerns not addressed".
Sadly, in the meantime, I had answered the question as asked now (under my influence). I let that sit and asked questions to refine it in the comments, waiting for the question to be re-opened.
That didn't happen; and I doubt it'll happen now!
So, having to switch machines, trying to help the original asker, and not wanting to let the work go to waste, I opened a new question that was different from the original question in that it was shorter, did not make the same mistakes, and added context from the asker's comments.
Promptly was closed as duplicate.
Now, I'm faced with a dilemma:

I don't want to modify the original question any further; it's likely (and a fair interpretation) that I'd be doing so to serve my answer.
I do want to see the question I answer asked – I think I the mouse-cloning problem pop up a couple of times in the last few years, and it's an interesting one. Usually, when one wants to see a question asked – you ask it! But now that's impossible, because it is inherently a duplicate of a too-bad-to-be-answered question, without being itself bad enough to be closed (aside its redundancy)

So, how do I move forward? Do I just roll back my improvements to the original question? That would solve the redundancy issue, I could ask to reopen my question, but it is very unfair to OP, who worked with me on it. I'm the high-rep user here, I'm not supposed to "steal" reputation and chances to interact on questions from lower-rep users! Also, obviously, making a question worse is actually vandalism, so I'd rather not resort to that.

I know the original question has been reopened but, if I could still vote to close it I would. Fundamentally it's a question about electronic devices in that the PC referred to is an electronic device that quite probably may not have very good (or accessible) documentation about how the mouse interconnects. Without that information being available it makes the question unanswerable just like someone asking how they can modify their TV set to add something or other.

@Andyaka "[...] may not have very good (or accessible) documentation about how the mouse interconnects." Well, the way a PC and a USB mouse communicate is specified in details in the USB device class definition for HID. The full specs are public (https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/hid1_11.pdf), so I'm a bit puzzled here. There's nothing that needs to be guessed.

Other than how to find that documentation and the willingness of someone to put it in the question @dim

@Andyaka Well, people knowledgeable in USB will know where it is, and this question is certainly directed at those people. There are tons of question on this site that I don't even know how to interpret, for example that poles and zeroes stuff, and I'm not closing those questions because people don't link to every resource necessary for me to comprehend them. I just accept that these questions aren't for me.

Thanks for the shout-out in the question. Yes, you made the situation complicated :) but I'll address some relevant points, and then while I was typing this answer, things changed...

You said that your self-answered question was: "Promptly was closed as duplicate.". No, actually I locked it. That's something different.
As it wasn't closed as a dup, it makes much of the rest of your question here now obsolete, as you talk about redundancy as if the new one was closed as a dup, but it wasn't. I locked it because it appears to be used as a way to post an answer to a closed question - which is not allowed. If we did allow that approach, then question closure would mean nothing, since people would bypass it like this!
Instead, my recommendation is to wait for the original question (which you kindly helped to improve) to get reopened. My suggestion (as I commented on your self-answered question) was for you to raise the original question and its plight here on Meta, as a calling to get it further reviewed by other site members (who could vote to reopen it, or keep it closed, as they judge - which is the whole point of community voting).
If the original question gets reopened, then you can answer that. We already know from the chat record, that the OP considers the answer to your self-answered question, to answer their (currently closed) original question. That is confirmation that (whether intended or not) your self-answered question has bypassed the closure of the original question. That's not good, and it's not a precedent that we can allow someone to try to set, even if they had good intentions and just wanted to post an answer.
Your currently-locked self-answered Q&A is likely to be deleted (for bypassing site quality control, as I explained). If you still have a valid, genuine follow-on self-answered question to post after that, then please go ahead - without trying to justify it in Meta explanation in the question :)

And while I was typing this, the original question was voted to be reopened. So, please, do answer that one as normal :)

thank you for the kind and patient explanation & reaction; I'd actually like to delete my question (and my answer to it) now. Can't, due to it being locked, but if you could do it for me, that would be much appreciated. You're right – I, just as much as the rest of the site, don't want this to become a precedent

@MarcusMüller - Thanks for your reply and for answering the original question, after it was reopened. I'll go ahead and delete your question. || It's all worked out OK in the end :)
